# CDF of a continuous random variable with discontinuity

Tags: probability, statistics

With a piecewise PDF defined as $$f(x)=\begin{cases}  1/2 &     -3 < x < -2 \\ 
e^{-2x} &     x>0\end{cases}$$

Would the CDF of this function between $-2$ and $0$ be $0.5$, even though it is not defined there?

And how would you calculate the mean, mode and variance of this PDF? For the mean, my answer turned out to be ~$0.18$ (which I believe is incorrect). I think the mode is $0$ as it's the highest point of the PDF, but variance I'm unsure of how to calculate.

Thanks!

Comment: The cdf is defined everywhere, so it is defined there. The pdf *should have been defined there* in the question, but wasn't.

Answer (score 1):

As usual, the mean is $\int_{-\infty}^\infty xf(x)\,dx$. Presumably the density function is intended to be $0$ where it has not been specified, since if we put it $0$ there, then $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,dx=1$.

So if we call our random variable $X$, we have
$$E(X)=\int_{-3}^{-2} \frac{x}{2}\,dx+\int_0^\infty xe^{-2x}\,dx.$$

For the variance, note that it is $E(X^2)-(E(X))^2$. Compute $E(X^2)$ in a way analogous to our computation of $E(X)$.

**Remarks:** $1.$ The density function in principle should be defined for all $x$ (or "almost all" $x$. There is, however, a convention that where it is not specified, it is $0$. So we can assume that $f(x)=0$ between $-2$ and $0$. It follows that the cdf is $\frac{1}{2}$ between $-2$ and $0$.

$2.$ The calculation of the mean, and of the variance, involves integration by parts. But if you know the mean and variance of the exponential with parameter $2$, you can use that knowledge to avoid some of the computations.